# debugging asp.net web service remotely

Tags: c#, debugging, asmx

I'm trying to attach to a Web service remotely from Visual Studio (2008). I can attach to processes on the remote machine, but when I attach to **w3wp.exe**, the breakpoints in my code say "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

Something I noticed is that after attaching, the DLL of the service doesn't appear in the list of loaded modules, but I can see other DLLs referenced in the project...

Am I attaching to the wrong process? Only one w3wp.exe instance runs on the remote machine...

---

**UPDATE**

Apparently, the remote debugger needs to be installed to allow stepping into web services, it cannot be done if the remote debugger is running from a share.

Since I couldn't make it work and I don't have access to the VS 2008 installer to properly install the debugger on the remote machine, I decided to upgrade the project to VS 2010 (of which I do have the installer)...

However, I still have to manually start the debugger and add permissions to be able to attach... Is there any way you can set additional permissions when the debugger runs as a service?

Comment: Do you have msvcmon installed on the remote server? I can't check right now for VS2008, but for later versions of VS, you also needed to ensure that under the project properties, you have the ASP.NET debugger checked (under the Web tab)

Comment: Yeah, I have all three debuggers (Native, ASP.NET and SQL) checked, and I don't have msvsmon __installed__ on the other machine, but I run it from a share in my dev. machine.

Comment: So, checking [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey7ec813%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it seems that to be able to step into Web Services, it is actually necessary to have the debugger service _installed_...

Answer (score 0):

If the debug symbol resources (`*.pdb`) are not right there with the libraries then I would say that your solution wasn't built for *Debug* but rather for *Release* (or some other build target).

I've personally not been able to attach the debugger to a project without those symbols being loadable.  As a solution I'd recommend rebuilding the project for *Debug* and then deploying it to the suspect environment that needs your debugger.

Comment: Well, I have `<compilation debug="true">`, and I get the .PDB in the bin folder after the build. Is there anything else I need to do to make debug-builds?